# Can a domain have zero NS records?

Tags: dns

My hosting provider is forbidding me to have zero NS records. But is that a written rule about DNS or just a way of my provider to prevent a fuckup?

For example, when I run `dig superuser.com NS`

> ```
> ;; ANSWER SECTION:
> superuser.com.        21599   IN  NS  ns-245.awsdns-30.com.
> superuser.com.        21599   IN  NS  ns-1699.awsdns-20.co.uk.
> superuser.com.        21599   IN  NS  ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com.
> superuser.com.        21599   IN  NS  ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com.
> ```

They give me four NS records

I know that its a best practise to have at least 2 records, but can you also have no records?

And then my second question

When a domain does not have any records, will some of the DNS records will be valid and reachable?

(I'm asking this question because I wrote a Use Case Test and also wrote a situation when a domain has no NS records and I want to know if that is possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not just a written rule, it is how DNS works. A domainname has the Name server listed so any browser can figure out who to contact in order to request the actual dns records.

The NS parameter holds a nameserver, and this server has the information on your domain stored. There are usually more than one Name Servers to make sure your domain keeps working if one of the servers goes offline.

Comment: I see, and why do the registry and the DNS both need to know those records?

Comment: To determine who owns the domain. Well the registrar does it for that. Its part of DNS, that's why DNS has it.

Answer (score 0):

DNS doesn't work without a nameserver for a domain.  There might be a registrar that lets you sign up without one, but no one on the external Internet will be able to resolve anything for that domain without at least one nameserver, which contains all the A and CNAME records, and so on.